# Return null inside the class

Tags: python

I'm wondering why my code below return null, however print command return proper value, could anyone explain my that?

```
class Newclass:
    def __init__(self,portal):   
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read("config.ini")
        self.connection_source=config.get(portal,'Sources')
    def getPortalSources(self):
       # print (connection_source)   ## Sources
        return self.connection_source

emp1 = Newclass('portalname')    
emp1.getPortalSources()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return null"?  Do you mean `None`?  Are you confusing `return` with a display on the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function but doing nothing with its return value.

Try to actually fetch and print it:

```
emp1 = Newclass('portalname')    
value = emp1.getPortalSources()  
print(value)
```

You may also want to catch that `configparser.NoOptionError` that waits to happen if `Sources` is not in the config file:

```
try:
    self.connection_source = config.get(portal,'Sources')
except configparser.NoOptionError:
    print("Couldn't find 'Sources' in conf file")
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought return value inside function is enough.Thanks

Comment: `ConfigParser.get()` throws `configparser.NoOptionError` rather than `KeyError` (and it isn't a subclass of `KeyError` either).

Comment: @Duncan I stand corrected. Guess I used to work with a custom subclass of it for too long now.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import configparser, os


class ConfigIni(dict, configparser.ConfigParser):
    def __init__(self, file):
        configparser.ConfigParser.__init__(self)
        self.iniFile=file
        if os.path.isfile(self.iniFile):
            self.read(self.iniFile)
            for section in self.sections():
                self[section] = {}

                for var in self.options(section):
                    val = self.get(section, var)
                    self[section][var] = val


f=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.ini')
print(ConfigIni(f))
```